# Tensorflow: strange behavior in cifar10 example using custom variable creation method

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

This is a follow up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41714801/tensorflow-variable-with-weight-decay-explanation/41717150#41717150).

I'm still working on the [cifar10 example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn/) on the file [cifar10.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10.py#L115) and noticed some strange behavior regarding the creation of variables.

But first a side-question: Why are the variables created with weight decay factor of `wd=0.0` and not `wd=None`? That way you would have less vertices in the computation graph.

Next, the strange behavior. I added the following function to make it more convenient to create variables:

```
def _create_variable(name, shape, initializer, wd=None):
  dtype = tf.float16 if FLAGS.use_fp16 else tf.float32

  with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    var = tf.get_variable(name, shape, dtype, initializer)

  if wd is not None:
    wd_val = tf.mul(tf.nn.l2_loss(var), wd, name='weight_loss')
    tf.add_to_collection('losses', wd_val)

  return var
```

When using this function to create the variables (with the original parameters), the logits that are computed come from a range of +-1e13 for the first batch, gradually getting better reaching +-1.5.  The loss on the other hand starts at around 400000 and gets bigger until it hits NaN.

When using the original functions to create the variables, the logits come from a range of +-1 right from the beginning and the loss start at around 4.5, gradually getting smaller.

Can somebody explain to me what the difference between my and the provided functions for variable generation is, and why the effect is so huge? I don't see it.

The full code of my modified cifar10.py can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/Cv3jVPPv). To test it out simple replace the original file with my version. To than switch between the original and my function simply change line 212 to `CUSTOM = False`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me! I used my own function the wrong way and passed the values for stddev as the mean and used the default stddev of 1.

The curse of not addressing the arguments by their name.

Anyway, why does this cause such a huge loss; sometimes even NaN?